# Javascript count DIVS and display result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to count a set of DIVS and return its number.

I have:

```
<div id="newsArea">

   <div class="newsTitle"><h1>News Title</h1></div>  
   <div class="newsContent">News content for post 1</div>


   <div class="newsTitle"><h1>News Title</h1></div>  
   <div class="newsContent">News content for post 2</div>


   <div class="newsTitle"><h1>News Title</h1></div>  
   <div class="newsContent">News content for post 3</div>


   <div class="newsTitle"><h1>News Title</h1></div>  
   <div class="newsContent">News content for post 4</div>

   <!-- etc and so on, depending on however many news stories.. -->

</div>
```

Is there a way in Javascript I can count how many times the newsTitle DIV appears and document.write a count, like:

```
document.write("There is a total of " + newsCountTotal "News stories")
```

Can I do something like:

```
var newsCountTotal;
newsCountTotal =  document.getElementByClassName("newsStories").length
```

(I hope you understand my logic).

Length is used to count, right? but how do I impliment what I'm after exactly? Do I need a For Loop to keep checking how many I have as well as .length ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Typically you would not use document.write.  Instead you would target another element and set the value as either it's value or innerHTML.

Comment: `.newsTitle h1 `?

Comment: @Mahi what about it?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.newsTitle h1').length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var storyCount = document.querySelectorAll('.newsTitle').length
document.querySelector('#storyCount').innerHTML = storyCount;
```

```html
<div id="newsArea">
   <div>(<span id="storyCount"></span>) Articles</div>

   <div class="newsTitle"><h1>News Title</h1></div>  
   <div class="newsContent">News content for post 1</div>


   <div class="newsTitle"><h1>News Title</h1></div>  
   <div class="newsContent">News content for post 2</div>


   <div class="newsTitle"><h1>News Title</h1></div>  
   <div class="newsContent">News content for post 3</div>


   <div class="newsTitle"><h1>News Title</h1></div>  
   <div class="newsContent">News content for post 4</div>

   <!-- etc and so on, depending on however many news stories.. -->

</div>
```